# Which user is running the most processes?

Tags: process, users, top

My `top` looks like this:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND          
 6524 asjzdiwq  30  10  500m  41m  24m S  0.0  0.3   0:15.27 php-cgi      
21274 asjzdiwq  30  10  500m  41m  24m S  0.0  0.3   0:04.97 php-cgi      
 9047 asjzdiwq  30  10  500m  40m  24m S  0.0  0.3   0:13.72 php-cgi      
26918 asjzdiwq  30  10  499m  40m  24m S  0.0  0.3   0:12.87 php-cgi      
13168 ahfvw0d1  30  10  498m  35m  20m S  0.0  0.2   0:03.49 php-cgi      
 8859 realnoni  30  10  495m  33m  20m S  0.0  0.2   0:11.27 php-cgi      
 6590 asjzdiwq  30  10  495m  32m  20m S  0.0  0.2   0:13.34 php-cgi      
 5657 holeyrai  30  10  495m  31m  19m S  0.0  0.2   0:04.47 php-cgi      
14480 ripplecr  30  10  498m  31m  17m S  0.0  0.2   0:02.90 php-cgi      
14442 ripplecr  30  10  497m  31m  17m S  0.0  0.2   0:02.00 php-cgi      
10720 computer  30  10  496m  31m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:08.75 php-cgi      
23821 loghome   30  10  496m  31m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:02.22 php-cgi      
17623 devilsti  30  10  495m  31m  19m S  0.0  0.2   0:05.81 php-cgi      
13305 realnoni  30  10  495m  30m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:06.29 php-cgi      
14461 ripplecr  30  10  496m  30m  17m S  0.0  0.2   0:01.47 php-cgi           
 8738 holeyrai  30  10  495m  30m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:03.37 php-cgi      
17569 devilsti  30  10  495m  30m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:05.73 php-cgi      
13174 ahfvw0d1  30  10  484m  30m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:04.00 php-cgi      
16126 realnoni  30  10  484m  30m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:12.08 php-cgi      
31561 a0w4pkbp  30  10  496m  30m  17m S  0.0  0.2   0:03.54 php-cgi      
31565 ahfvw0d1  30  10  484m  29m  17m S  0.0  0.2   0:05.80 php-cgi      
21275 asjzdiwq  30  10  484m  29m  18m S  0.0  0.2   0:01.77 php-cgi
```

You can see that the same "USER" can have multiple "COMMAND"s running as "php-cgi".  I would like to find out which user is running the most processes and get a count of how many processes they are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count all processes per user:

```
ps -eo user|sort|uniq -c|sort -n
```

or to just have the ones running php-cgi:

```
ps -eo user:15,cmd|sed -n '/php-cgi/s/ .*//p'|sort|uniq -c|sort -n
```

Comment: Thanks - the first command works well and displays the full usernames!  The second command works correctly, but it displays most of the USERS with UID and not the full usernames.

Comment: I think it is because your usernames are longer than the default width of the field. Try giving an explicit width `ps -eo user:15,cmd|...`. I've edited this into my answer.

Comment: Setting it to 15 made most of the usernames appear, but 20 made them all appear - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps`. From `man ps`:

> -U userlist
>   Select by real user ID (RUID) or name.
>                          It selects the processes whose real user name or ID is
>                          in the userlist list. The real user ID identifies the
>                          user who created the process, see getuid(2).
>
> -u userlist
>   Select by effective user ID (EUID) or name.
>                          This selects the processes whose effective user name or
>                          ID is in userlist. The effective user ID describes the
>                          user whose file access permissions are used by the
>                          process (see geteuid(2)). Identical to U and --user.

So for example to see all processes of user `asjzdiwq`, you can use:

```
ps -u asjzdiwq  ## Using RUID
ps -U asjzdiwq  ## Using EUID
```